# How to enable breakpoint in Visual Studio 2013 for Cordova application

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I am developing a cordova based hybrid application targeted for Windows 8.1 platform.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 to develop and test the application. I have also installed Apache Cordova Tools for Visual Studio 2013. But then also, I am unable to debug  the application. The breakpoint never hits. The error at breakpoint says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you got this resolved.  Have you tried putting your code into a separate .JS file and referencing that from your page?  I had the same problem when I wrote my first Cordova app and just thought I'd try putting the code in a separate file and the breakpoints started to work.